# Angularjs response not printing in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to print the response from my controller to my form. But it is not printing the messages passed from it.

Here is my controller .js file

```
app.controller('regCtrl', function ($scope) {
});
$scope.doRegister = function ()
    {
        username = $scope.signup.registerUserName;
        email = $scope.signup.email;
        password = $scope.signup.registerPassword;
        $http({
            url: 'app/toolkit/calls/doRegister.php',
            method: "GET",
            params: {username: username, email: email, password: password}
        }).success(function (status, data, response, header) {
            $scope.data.msg = 'Account not Activated'
             });
    };
```

and in the form i have

```
<div ng-controller="regCtrl">
<div ng-if="data.show" ng-bind="data.msg"></div>
```

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i make the response messages print in the form.

Comment: declare `$scope.data= {};` inside controller..will follow the `dot rule`

Comment: `$scope.data= {}; ` is already inside the controller right...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by turning it the `$scope.data` `true` by

```
$scope.data = {show: true};
```

then it works.